# Kendo UI Editor - Get current font style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I'm currently working with Kendo UI Editor and having some issues trying to get the current font style. Basically, what I would like to do is get the following values using Javascript or jQuery:

Values I want to get:

[image]

Also(and if possible), I would like to get the other styles that could be activated such as Bold, italic, underline, etc. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(".k-editor").find(".k-fontName").val();
$(".k-editor").find(".k-fontSize").val();
```

**EDIT:**

To make sure Bold, Italic, Underline is checked:

```
$(".k-editor").find(".k-tool").filter("[title='Bold']").hasClass("k-state-selected");
$(".k-editor").find(".k-tool").filter("[title='Italic']").hasClass("k-state-selected");
$(".k-editor").find(".k-tool").filter("[title='Underline']").hasClass("k-state-selected");
```

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunatelly, I'm still getting undefined. Tried with similar variations but didn't work.

Comment: Could you post an example of how your editor is defined?

Comment: Sure, here's an example:  $("#templateEditor_")

Comment: Instead of writing code in comments - edit your post

Comment: Judt did it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Could you also post how is your editor definition look like? Not only the way you call a widget? I'd like to reproduce your example and to do that you must provide more information.

Comment: My bad, I changed one charachter while pasting your original answer and that's why I was getting undefined. Just fix that and it's working perfectly!! Thank you so much for your time and patience!!

Comment: Just one final question, is there a way to get values such as if Bold, Italic, underlined, etc? If not, your question already helped me a lot

Comment: Yes, just check out my Edit